# Multiple web applications on one Ubuntu server how do I access via URL

Tags: networking, apache2, dns

I am hosting two applications on one Ubuntu server.

Grafana on *.*.*.*:3000
LibreNMS on *.*.*.*:80

Before I had Grafana setup I accessed Librenms via Librenms.URL.com after creating an alias in my DNS to the server address.

I now want to be able to access Librenms with the same URL but I also want to be able to access Grafana at Grafana.URL.com.

At the moment this is only on my internal network.

I understand ill have to move LibrNMS off of port 80 to make this work.

How can I achieve this? probably some simple config with Apache?

Thanks